# Multiply the number of clicks of the selected button and the other button

Tags: javascript

I have 2 buttons with values. For example, the value of the first button is 10, the value of the second button is 100. I also have an independent button A, and I need to get the number of times this button is clicked. That is, when I choose one of the 2 buttons with values, for example, when I select the button with the value of 10 and how many times I click on the A button, I want these values ​​to multiply, how can I?

[image: I have button values ​​as below]

[image: If this is the shape, I need to find out how many times it was clicked.]

I can get the value of the button as below

```
<div id="container">
        <button class="buttonbetbox" id="10" onclick="reply_click(this.id)"></button>
 </div>

function reply_click(id) 
 {}
```

In this way, I can get how many times the button was clicked.

```
<button class="buttoncrab" id="btncrab" onclick="myFunction()">
        </button>

function myFunction() {
            count++;
        }
```

As I explained above, I need to get the product of the selected button value and the number of times the other button was clicked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can save the number of times a button is clicked and the last selected value in variables in the global scope, and then do your multiplication:

```
var numberOfClicks = 0;
var currentlySelected = 10;

function reply_click(nb) {
        if (nb == 10) {
            currentlySelected = 10;
    } else {
                currentlySelected = 100;
    }
    
    numberOfClicks = 0;
}

function multiplyCount() {
    numberOfClicks++;
    console.log(numberOfClicks*currentlySelected);
}
```

See https://jsfiddle.net/81z62jxb/ for example on display in HTML

Comment: You may have misunderstood. Think of it this way, there is a button with a value of 10 and I clicked it. I got the value of 10 right now. I have another button and I clicked this button 20 times. I want to multiply these two values. @Ben

Comment: In my code, when you click on the "10" button, it multiplies 10 by the number of times you clicked on the "100" button. Isn't that what you're asking ?

Comment: when I click on the 10 button 1 time, then it says 100 no matter how many times I click on the 100 button. In fact, when I click the 10 button 1 time and then click the 100 button 5 times, it should write 500 @Ben

Comment: "when I click on the 10 button 1 time, then it says 100" --> In my jsfiddle (and in my code), when you click on the 10 button, it says 0 in the console. If you're seeing 100, that's a problem with your code.

Comment: "when I click the 10 button 1 time and then click the 100 button 5 times, it should write 500" --> Ok you really have to clarify what you need, because the only way to reach 500 in your example is to multiply the value of the button (100) by the number of times this same button has been clicked (5).

Comment: Let's think of it another way : 
1) I click on the 10 button
2) Then I click twice on the 100 button
3) Then I click twice on the 10 button
Can you tell me what you want to happen at each step ?

Comment: I want exactly this. In the first photo, I have a button with a value of 10 that I pressed, surrounded by yellow. After selecting this button, if I click the round button in the 2nd photo 5 times, I want it to perform the 5*10 operation. @Ben

Comment: OK, got you, give me a minute.

Comment: thank you so much, sorry for tiring you @Ben

Comment: No problem, it may not be your fault english is not my main language :)